# dynamically using JPA EntityManager without creating entities

Tags: database, jpa, jdbc

I have the requirement of dynamically connecting to different `DataSources` of different types(for example MySQL, Oracle, ...) and executing complex queries with `CriteriaBuilder` and such. Since these databases can have different schemas; I cannot have their entities, but at run-time I have the String values of table names, columns, database type and such. Can I use JPA to dynamically create database specific queries without having defined the entities?

Other ideas are welcome.

Comment: Why can you not have entities when persisting classes to differing schemas? You could have an orm.xml for each schema easily enough

Comment: @NeilStockton these databases are user provided I have no idea about their schemas. I will try to make it more obvious in the question

Comment: When using JPA with *any* schema (whether user-provided or developer-provided) you still have to map between classes and tables. And that is where orm.xml could be used. If you dont want to do it then just use JDBC!

Comment: @NeilStockton there are no entity classes. using JDBC means I have to implement the SQL for every database I would like to support. I would rather let some library/framework create databse specific SQL for me.

Comment: JPA needs entity classes, you have no entity classes. Conclusion : you cannot use JPA. Cant get simpler

Comment: @NeilStockton it does answer my question that JPA cannot handle this, but I was hoping some people could provide alternate solutions.